# How to add an application to Apache Brooklyn catalog

Tags: brooklyn

I am trying to add applications into Brooklyn catalog. can anyone explain steps to add a new application to catalog.xml?

I did try the sample catalog provided at https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/v/0.7.0-M1/use/guide/quickstart/policies-and-catalogs.html . The application gets listed in catalog tab but when I try to launch it, it gets stuck at 'configuring'. Is there something else that needs to be done ?

I tried adding existing application to catalog ( https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/v/latest/ops/catalog/index.html ) but it failed. Can anyone help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend upgrading to 0.7.0-M2-incubating, as the catalog has significantly improved since 0.7.0-M1. The documentation at https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/v/latest/ops/catalog/index.html describes the steps for 0.7.0-M2-incubating; they will not work for 0.7.0-M1.

The link to an explicit version of the docs (rather than latest) is https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/v/0.7.0-M2-incubating/ops/catalog/index.html

There are also more improvements in snapshot (and in existing pull requests), if you fancy trying the bleeding edge!

For the 0.7.0-M1 error "gets stuck at configuring", we'd need more info (e.g. logs, etc). Suggest you e-mail the mailing list or jump on IRC if it's still a problem (https://brooklyn.incubator.apache.org/community/mailing-lists.html).